# tracemode attribute is not allowed in App Config

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm trying to trace a SOAP web service written in C# using the 4.0 .Net Framework.

After following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
i configured the app config of my web service client in the following way:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
    <listeners>
      <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="trace.log"/>
</sharedListeners>
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
</switches>
```

This works, however i don't need to see the hexadecimal code in the trace log. The tutorial i mentioned said i needed to set the "tracemode" attribute to "protocolonly". However when i add this attribute visual studio tells me that this attribute is not valid.

I tried to run the program anyway. However when i create an instance of my Web Service class i get a "TypeInitializationException". If i remove the tracemode attribute the client works fine but  i still get the Hexadecimal codes in my trace log.

Comment: Upon reading more carefully i found this:

"Optional String attribute. Set to includehex to show protocol traces in hexadecimal and text format. Set to protocolonly to show only text. The default value is includehex.

This attribute must be set on the <switches> element as shown in the example. An exception is thrown if this attribute is set on an element under the <source> element."

Answer (score 5):

If you add the "tracemode" attribute VS will say it's not allowed, however the log file does now include the full XML data.

Here is my app.config snippet:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly">
```

Without tracemode:

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [9992] Data from ConnectStream#56298650::Write
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [9992] 00000000 : 3C 73 3A 45 6E 76 65 6C-6F 70 65 20 78 6D 6C 6E : <s:Envelope xmln
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [9992] 00000010 : 73 3A 73 3D 22 68 74 74-70 3A 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 : s:s="http://sche
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [9992] 00000020 : 6D 61 73 2E 78 6D 6C 73-6F 61 70 2E 6F 72 67 2F : mas.xmlsoap.org/
```

With tracemode:

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7524] ConnectStream#57911184::Write()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7524] Data from ConnectStream#57911184::Write
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7524] <<<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetCloseOutList xmlns="http://adsionline.com/ADSIShippingWS/"><shipperFriendlyName>GREENWOOD</shipperFriendlyName><carrierFriendlyName>FedEx GroundÂ®</carrierFriendlyName></GetCloseOutList></s:Body></s:Envelope>>>
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7524] Exiting ConnectStream#57911184::Write() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7524] ConnectStream#57911184::Close()
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7524] Exiting ConnectStream#57911184::Close()
```

I'm not sure why it complains and still works.  But it works, guess that's the important thing.